# Programmatically capture Full GC count

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm trying to capture the full GCs which occur in our Java application.  So far I have two approaches, both with flaws:

1. Poll the GarbageCollectorMXBean objects every x seconds, then try to pull the GC time and the GC count since the last poll and try to detect how long a GC occurred.  Unfortunately with this, we don't know if it's a Full GC.
2. Use javax.management.NotificationListener, the subscribe to the GarbageCollectorMXBean notifications.  In theory, the application will then be notified when a GC occurs, with the text "end of major GC" and "end of minor GC" as well as a cause.  The flaw of this approach is that the duration seems to be wildly incorrect (sometimes showing 898 seconds when the GC log will show .2 seconds) and there is the mysterious case "No GC" which seems to indicate no GC was actually performed (as there was no entry in the gc log).

A hybrid approach is possible where the GC MXBeans can be queried when I get a GC notification, then check if a GC has been performed.  The downside of this is that the No GC cause might still trigger at the end of "major GC" and cause the logic to be more complex.

What I'm really after is the total amount of time the application has been paused due to GC operations.  I figure that capturing a full GC will be adequate to indicate that the application has halted for a period of time, so that if we detect frequent GCs we know there is heavy usage or the application will run out of memory shortly.  Is there a better solution to detecting GC time and whether there was a full GC?

**Edit**: To be clear, I would like to capture this information inside the given JVM.  This JVM is controlled by a separate team, and we don't necessary have control over the JVM arguments they will set, we can only make recommendations.  The idea is similar to flight recorder, but instead providing information in real time to administrators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the hotspot specific GC beans, then you can new/old distinction, not concurrent/full. But that is in most cases enough.

In that case I would poll, and use the before/after informations in `#LastGCInfo` from the relevant generation:

For example `java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS Scavenge` is the young generation and `java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep` the old generation when ParallelOld is enabled.

With CMS you see concurrent collections and the full collections in `java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=ConcurrentMarkSweep` (but hopefully there is never a full collection :)

This is GC and VM specific, so it needs some heuristics to support all platforms you care about.

I think more fine-grained monitoring is only possible with the Flight Recorder events, but I havent have experience with that.

Comment: Both of these are typically returned with java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans(), right?

Comment: This ultimately got me closest to the goal, I ended up waiting for the GC notification from the garbage collector beans, then once I was notified of a GC event I would analyze the previous values of the total time and the total number of GCs to determine the average time since last notification.  That would allow me to have the cause, the GC name, and the effective GC time.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for GC notifications. See code below.

I'm crossposting this answer here since it seems relevant. Based on [pointers given by @the8472 in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495280/how-to-detect-a-long-gc-from-within-a-jvm) I crafted a more complete sample for logging GC from inside JVM (and thus detecting/counting it). I hope this will save somebody some time :)

```
package fi.pelam.gclogutil;
import java.lang.management.*;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData;
import javax.management.*;

import com.sun.management.GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo;
import com.sun.management.GcInfo;

public class GcLogUtil {
    static public void startLoggingGc() {
        // http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=javax.management.MBeanServerConnection&method=addNotificationListener
        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html#GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION
        for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gcMbean : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
            try {
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().
                        addNotificationListener(gcMbean.getObjectName(), listener, null,null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static private NotificationListener listener = new NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
            if (notification.getType().equals(GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html
                CompositeData cd = (CompositeData) notification.getUserData();
                GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo gcNotificationInfo = GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.from(cd);
                GcInfo gcInfo = gcNotificationInfo.getGcInfo();
                System.out.println("GarbageCollection: "+
                        gcNotificationInfo.getGcAction() + " " +
                        gcNotificationInfo.getGcName() +
                        " duration: " + gcInfo.getDuration() + "ms" +
                        " used: " + sumUsedMb(gcInfo.getMemoryUsageBeforeGc()) + "MB" +
                        " -> " + sumUsedMb(gcInfo.getMemoryUsageAfterGc()) + "MB");
            }
        }
    };

    static private long sumUsedMb(Map<String, MemoryUsage> memUsages) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (MemoryUsage memoryUsage : memUsages.values()) {
            sum += memoryUsage.getUsed();
        }
        return sum / (1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the file system of the JVM in question, you can tell the JVM to log information about garbage collections.

For Oracle Java 8 several flags exist (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABFAFAE)

---

**-XX:+PrintGC**

Enables printing of messages at every GC. By default, this option is disabled.

**-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime**

Enables printing of how much time elapsed since the last pause (for example, a GC pause). By default, this option is disabled.

**-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime**

Enables printing of how much time the pause (for example, a GC pause) lasted. By default, this option is disabled.

**-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps**

Enables printing of a date stamp at every GC. By default, this option is disabled.

**-XX:+PrintGCDetails**

Enables printing of detailed messages at every GC. By default, this option is disabled.

**-XX:+PrintGCTaskTimeStamps**

Enables printing of time stamps for every individual GC worker thread task. By default, this option is disabled.

**-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps**

Enables printing of time stamps at every GC. By default, this option is disabled.

Comment: Just to be clear, this solution would either be capturing the standard out or the gc log, then parsing that information to determine whether a Full GC occurred?  Wouldn't parsing the log file be difficult, as changing any of the above mentioned flags change the format of the output?

Comment: This is intrinsically vendor dependent.  I have not looked into the Java 8 log format yet.  The Java 7 gc log was a reasonably easy XMl dialect.

Comment: Java 7 and 8 logfiles are pretty messed up. If you have seen an XML dialect, then it was the IBM logs, which are pretty. IBM also has a trace buffer to access those structured events.

Answer (score 1):

Through the name of GarbageCollectorMXBean, we can deduce which one is responsible the execution of full gc.

```
GarbageCollectorMXBean fullGcMXBean = null;
        List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> gcMxBeanList = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
        for(GarbageCollectorMXBean gcMxBean: gcMxBeanList){
            if(gcMxBean.getName().endsWith("MarkSweep")){
                fullGcMXBean = gcMxBean;
                break;
            }
        }
```