# How to detect a long gc from within a JVM?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How can I detect a GC (**Edit** or any stall)  which exceeds some configured app timeout so that I can log a warning (or dynamically extend the timeout)?

**Edit** I am not asking for alternatives or workarounds like monitoring. I am writing a library and I cannot control the environment or settings. Whilst I will clearly document that users of the library must set an appropriate timeout I still expect people to overlook that else change jvm heap settings years later and forget to increase the timeouts. Support will be simpler if I can warn in the library logging of a possible pause greater than the configured timeouts. It doesn't have to be perfect detection "good enough" would reduce time wasted on library users not setting a sensible timeout.

**Edit** and to be clear the library works fine even if there is a big GC yet there is a good reason to have well chosen timeout which is to detect a crash such that the library tries to connect to an alternate peer.

Answer (score 9):

Based on pointers given by @the8472 above I crafted a bit more complete sample for logging GC from inside the JVM (and thus detecting it). I hope this will save somebody some time :)

```
package fi.pelam.gclogutil;
import java.lang.management.*;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData;
import javax.management.*;

import com.sun.management.GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo;
import com.sun.management.GcInfo;

public class GcLogUtil {
    static public void startLoggingGc() {
        // http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=javax.management.MBeanServerConnection&method=addNotificationListener
        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html#GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION
        for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gcMbean : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
            try {
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().
                        addNotificationListener(gcMbean.getObjectName(), listener, null,null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static private NotificationListener listener = new NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
            if (notification.getType().equals(GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html
                CompositeData cd = (CompositeData) notification.getUserData();
                GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo gcNotificationInfo = GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.from(cd);
                GcInfo gcInfo = gcNotificationInfo.getGcInfo();
                System.out.println("GarbageCollection: "+
                        gcNotificationInfo.getGcAction() + " " +
                        gcNotificationInfo.getGcName() +
                        " duration: " + gcInfo.getDuration() + "ms" +
                        " used: " + sumUsedMb(gcInfo.getMemoryUsageBeforeGc()) + "MB" +
                        " -> " + sumUsedMb(gcInfo.getMemoryUsageAfterGc()) + "MB");
            }
        }
    };

    static private long sumUsedMb(Map<String, MemoryUsage> memUsages) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (MemoryUsage memoryUsage : memUsages.values()) {
            sum += memoryUsage.getUsed();
        }
        return sum / (1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes used in this code are com.sun.* and are marked as "is not API" on rt.jar. Need to find another way to receive the same information...

Comment: @VladimirDyuzhev I think in recent OpenJDK versions the [module `jdk.management` includes the `GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html). But it should be available. I haven't tried this yet. It makes sense to not have this in core APIs as the GC is an internal detail. And of course other JDK implementations may not provide this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use management bean [notifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/Notification.html?is-external=true) and subscribe to [GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html) events which in turn provide `GcInfo` objects with the stats you want.

The [`javax.management` package javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/package-summary.html) have a high level overview how to use those services.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what I am about to say does not apply to real-time systems, so let's get this immediately out of the way: If you want to build a real-time system with stringent constraints, then Java might not be the way to go.

Now, if you are ***not*** building a real-time system, then I would advise against being overly concerned about the possibility that GC might slow down your program, delay your program, freeze your program, etc.

Garbage collection in modern garbage-collected languages like java is highly streamlined, it works on a separate thread, it does as much of its work as possible in as small chunks as possible, and the chances of you witnessing a freeze-up due to garbage-collection are very slim.

On the other hand, in any modern non-real-time system there are so many different things that can happen that may slow down or temporarily freeze your program, (most importantly, *paging*) that the contribution of GC will be negligible and most likely lost in the noise.

***Amendment***

After your amendment to your question, it appears that your need is to detect whether your runtime environment is experiencing high irregularities in the allocation of computing resources (CPU.)  This is a much more general problem than detecting delays due to GC.  (GC is just one possible source of such delays, and not even among the first suspects.)  So, to solve for the general purpose, consider the following approach:

Create a separate thread which does the following in a loop:

```
1. record the current time.
2. sleep for a specific number of milliseconds. (Say, 50.)
3. record the current time again.
```

In a smoothly running system, the difference between the first and the second time should be very close to the amount of sleep.  If your system is experiencing irregularities, then this time will vary wildly.  Such wild variations persisting over a considerable period of time would mean that you have a system which is not running smoothly.

If you are really hell-bent on catching the GC freezing your program, you can make sure to perform some memory allocation between steps 2 and 3 above.  Presumably, if the GC has frozen your java VM, it will take some time before this memory allocation gets honored.  Trust me, it won't happen, but if that will give you peace of mind, then go ahead and test for it.

You can also further elaborate on this technique by synchronizing it with the main logic of your program so as to make sure that the main logic is alive and running.

Comment: Thanks for amending. I upvoted and deleted the comments which were critical that the answer was off-topic. I also edited the question that yes large GC is only one such issue any pause can be relevant to a timeout.

Comment: Okay, I cleaned up things from my side, too.

Comment: 1. No GC algorithm has eliminated stop-the-world phases. 2. Minor GC is always stop-the-world. 3. Full GC can stop the world for 30 seconds or more on a large heap (> 100GB, for example). GC pauses are a very real concern in high-end server systems.

Comment: "No GC algorithm has eliminated stop-the-world phases.", azul's Zing VM did for practical purposes. I.e.  they only require constant-time, millisecond STW pauses regardless of heap size. And they claim that's an implementation detail that can be eliminated in the future.

Answer (score 0):

regarding handling any timeout you can run your task inside a future http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html
you then create a different thread to monitor the Future run, which checks if it is done, if it is not done by the timeout you specified you issue a warning in log or something.

```
ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 ) ;
        Future<?> submit = svc.submit(r);
```

//sleep for timeout.

```
if(!submit.isDone())
{
  log.warn("action is not done");
}
```

you can return the answer to the task with `submit.get` with timeout or without.

Comment: I am not sure that helps with a full GC as everything will stop. If the timeout was 1s and a full GC takes, say, 10s then both the job and the future may finish in any order after 10s. If the job happens to finish first the future would not detect the problem had occurred.

Comment: Yes, it seems like you are correct, but it will help for any other reason I think, I thought of using Future.get but it seems to do something very similar

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a working trick which basically does `Thread.sleep(1000)` on a watcher thread and measures the actual time spent in sleep. If it exceeds a threshold lets say 500ms, it likely means a long stop-the-world GC pause.